# Use Nested fied type in AggregatingMergeTree for ClickHouse

Tags: nested, clickhouse, materialized-views

This is my data schema of CH:

```
CREATE TABLE testing
(
    id UInt64,
    client_id UInt64,
    nested_field Nested(
        key String,
        value1 UInt32,
        value2 UInt32
    )
) ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

This is AggregatingMergeTree table schema what I want to have:

```
CREATE TABLE testing_agg
(
    client_id UInt32,
    records AggregateFunction(count, UInt32),
    nested_field Nested(
        key String,
        value1 AggregateFunction(sum, UInt32),
        value2 AggregateFunction(sum, UInt32)
    )
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (client_id);
```

Does clickhouse supports this type of aggregation? how to write the correct Materialized view for it?

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account the aggregate functions you are using, you can achieve it by using `SummingMergeTree` engine, the only extra consideration is that nested field should end by `Map`.

An example:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testing_agg;
CREATE TABLE testing_agg
(
    client_id UInt32,
    records UInt32,
    nestedMap Nested(
        key String,
        value1 UInt32,
        value2 UInt32
    )
) ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (client_id);

INSERT INTO testing_agg VALUES (1, 10, ['1', '2'], [1, 3], [2, 4]);
INSERT INTO testing_agg VALUES (1, 10, ['1'], [2], [1]);
INSERT INTO testing_agg VALUES (1, 10, ['3'], [4], [3]);

SELECT * FROM testing_agg FINAL;


┌─client_id─┬─records─┬─nestedMap.key─┬─nestedMap.value1─┬─nestedMap.value2─┐
│         1 │      30 │ ['1','2','3'] │ [3,3,4]          │ [3,4,3]          │
└───────────┴─────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

More info: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/summingmergetree/#nested-structures

Comment: yeah right, but how to do that with AggregatingMergeTree :)

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that with AggregatingMergeTree